# Google maps api 3 with places DEMO works only in Chrome... why?

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

There's a lot of Google Maps API Places info on here already, but here's a demo which show a lot of what many people seem to be having problems with, sadly though it only works in Chrome (at least not in Firefox or IE).

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/places/2012-may-hangout/search.html

Can anyone explain why? it has a lot of unnecessary things like animated dropping of markers, but has a really good example of the difference between google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE; and google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE; presenting ordered markers and reasults in a table with type icons.

Answer (score 0):

I just visited the link in your question, using IE8, and it seems to run fine:

[image]

What is the problem you are having in IE?

Comment: Hi Sean,<BR> Same happens in Firefox and IE9... map and elements all fine, but when you press search resets all check boxes, search box and produces no results - effectively resets.

Comment: A better example that seems to work well with all browsers can be seen in Google Geo Developers Blog: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/google-places-api-search-refinements-as.html or a direct link to the demo here: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/places/keyword_rankBy.html

Comment: That's really nice Chris! Unfortunately I speant a whole host of time hacking something based around this: http://bestfromgoogle.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/add-local-search-to-google-maps.html (rather than Local it seems to tap into wider search stuff - which does make it significantly easier to display details of business, provides link to Google page of business - although it does display some "interesting" results on ocasion!)

Comment: EDIT: having just played about with both, obviously one you linked to does show details... but getting better rural result in UK on older one e.g "clothing store" 1 obscure shown using Places, whereas older one shows 6 high street names :S